# Fazer redirecionamento para página anterior: PHP vs. JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, link, navegação

Qual é a maneira mais vantajosa para fazer o usuário voltar para a página anterior. Por exemplo, no frond-end ficaria assim:

```
<a href="window.history.back()">Voltar</a>
```

Já no back-end seria algo semelhante a isso:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; ?>">Voltar</a>
```

- Qual é a abordagem mais adequada?
- Existem abordagens melhores?
- Quais alternativas mais seguras existem para fazer isso no back-end?

Comment: No front-end, pois é quando os dados já foram gerenciados no banco e recebeu uma resposta de que está tudo okay (ou não).

Comment: @EdwardRamos Como assim? Ambos os redirecionamentos da pergunta são no frontend, a única diferença é que o primeiro utiliza a API `history` do navegador e a segunda define a URL com base nos dados da requisição recebida pelo PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Importante salientar que as suas duas soluções fazem o redirecionamento no frontend. Não é porque tem um trecho de PHP ali que ele faz no backend; o PHP só será responsável por gerar o HTML entregue pela resposta HTTP.

**Primeira regra do desenvolvimento web?** Você não fala sobre desenvolvimento web. **Segunda regra do desenvolvimento web?** Você não fala sobre desenvolvimento web. **Terceira regra do desenvolvimento web?** Jamais confie nos dados da requisição HTTP recebida.

A sua segunda opção, talvez não saiba, é inteiramente baseada em um dado da requisição HTTP que o PHP está tratando, referente ao cabeçalho HTTP `Referer`. A própria [documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/reserved.variables.server.php) do PHP, que já deve ter lido, te alerta sobre ele:

> `HTTP_REFERER`
>
> O endereço da página (se houver) através da qual o agente do usuário acessou a página atual. Essa diretiva é informada pelo agente do usuário. **Nem todos os browsers geram esse heade**r, e alguns ainda possuem a habilidade de modificar o conteúdo do HTTP_REFERER como recurso. Em poucas palavras, **não é confiável**.

Partes destacadas por minha conta. Resumindo, não há justificativas para você deixar sua aplicação dependente de algo que pode não estar definido e, quando está, pode não ser confiável.

Por outro lado, você tem uma API para gerenciamento de histórico estável, gerenciado pelo próprio navegador. Seu usuário está em um navegador, sua intenção é que ele volte a página anterior, ninguém melhor para te dizer qual é esta página que o próprio navegador.

Fora isso, a API `history` do navegador é compatível com as alterações que a própria aplicação pode querer fazer no histórico. A aplicação pode, por exemplo, fazer uso de `history.pushState` para definir pontos no histórico para estados da própria página e permitir que o usuário queira navegar entre tais estados com as ferramentas do navegador. A título de exemplo, pode ser desejado que após aberto um modal na tela o botão Voltar do navegador feche-o fazendo com que o usuário retorne ao estado anterior, que era a página com o modal fechado. Nesses casos, seu link para voltar estaria condizente com o comportamento da própria aplicação. Com o link definido com PHP o usuário seria redirecionado independente dos estados internos da página.

Portanto, utilize `window.history.back()`, ele é suportado por 97.04% dos navegadores atuais, conforme [Can I Use](https://caniuse.com/#search=history).

Comment: @rcs Como assim usar sessões? Não entendi a relação entre a sessão e o redirecionamento para a página anterior.

Comment: Aí depende exclusivamente dos requisitos do sistema. Fazer redirecionamento no frontend ou no backend são coisas bem distintas.